# We wound up on the shore of our own subconcious

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase in the title mean?

[Source](http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/We_Built_Our_Own_World):

> We were working together, we were exploring the concept of a dream
>   within a dream. I kept pushing things. I wanted to go deeper and
>   deeper, I wanted to go… further. I just didn’t understand the concept
>   that hours could turn into years down there. That we could get trapped
>   so deep that when **we wound up on the shore of our own subconscious** we
>   lost sight of what was real. We created, we built the world for
>   ourselves. We did that for years. We built our own world.

I presume "wound up" means completely the same as "ended up" would mean. But what's that got to do with shores?

Comment: It's the past form of *wind up*, which means the same as *end up*. Shores is used in a fihurative meaning here. I thunk they mean that their dreams were pretty/beautiful, just like shores are.

Comment: If you think of "subconscious" as a sea, does that help?

Comment: Yes, the "sea of consciousness" is a fairly common metaphor ..... http://www.google.com/search?q=sea+of+consciousness&hl=en&biw=320&bih=356&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAGoVChMInoqRr9WMxgIVzqSICh0i7w4t&dpr=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subconscious has *shores* (beaches), the subconscious is metaphorically an ocean.

To "wind up" often means to find oneself at a place having taken unfamiliar paths; one is uncertain where the road is going to lead.

Comment: Well, I thought that wind up meant here exactly the same as end up. __We end up on the shore of our own subconscious__ sounds nonsensical to youy, doesn't it? About the subconscious is an ocean, it's pretty clear.

Comment: BTW, you said having taken unfamiliar paths. What's that mean? having taken, I don't understand this phrase in the sentence.

Comment: *having taken* (having + past participle) establishes the time of the action: the taking of unfamiliar paths happened before we find ourselves at the destination.   *Having taken his last exam, he felt free to party late into the night*.  The reference time is concurrent with the time of his feeling free to party; the taking of the last exam is prior to that reference time.

Comment: *end up* sounds no more nonsensical than *we find ourselves* :)

Comment: So __Having taken his last exam, he felt free to party late into the night.__ = __He's taken his last exam, so he felt free to party late into the night.__?

Comment: I believe you understand, but because both actions took place in the past and do not touch the present in any way, we wouldn't use present perfect (has taken) to express the idea.  He took the exam on Friday afternoon and Friday night he felt free to party. *Having taken his last exam on Friday afternoon, he felt free to party late on Friday night.*